# How to embed a Chart into Google Sheets Using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts, google-visualization

I have a table of data, could be from 2000 lines to 10,000 lines of data. They are pulled automatically from an API, you can find an example without personal identifiers here - [google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18dHvqa4myTvuOMaElwNNHBbtcGF3vuOrjGra2AcMv40/edit?usp=sharing).

As you can see, in the table, on the posts Tab, I have a column called Media Category, and I have created pivot tables in corresponding tabs called article stats, etc. All this is generated through Google Apps Scripts.

I would like to do the same with different charts. I can't use the normal newChart() because I need to create a datable that only has the rows corresponding to the media category that I want to input into the particular tab.

The code for this is here.

```
  var tableStructure = {
    'filters': [],
    'columns':[
        {
          'name':'Publish Date',
          'type':Charts.ColumnType.DATE,
          'columnNumber':4
        },
        {
          'name':'Comments',
          'type':Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER,
          'columnNumber':7
        },
        {
          'name':'Likes',
          'type':Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER,
          'columnNumber':8
        },
        {
          'name':'Appreciations',
          'type':Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER,
          'columnNumber':9
        },
        {
          'name':'Praises',
          'type':Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER,
          'columnNumber':10
        },
        {
          'name':'Empathy',
          'type':Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER,
          'columnNumber':11
        },
    ]
  };

  for (var sT in socialTypes) {
     var typeName = socialTypes[sT];
     //sees if adgroup ad sheet exists, if not, creates it
    if (sheet.getSheetByName(typeName+' Stats') == null) {
      sheet.insertSheet(typeName+' Stats',10);
    
     }

    var anchoredCell = sheet.getSheetByName(typeName+' Stats').getRange("G1");
    var statsSheet = sheet.getSheetByName(typeName+' Stats');
    tableStructure.filters.splice(0);
    tableStructure.filters.push({'filterValue':typeName,'filterColumn':2});
    //create datatable
    var dataTable = createDataTable(table,tableStructure);

    //creates chart
    var lineBuilder = statsSheet.newChart()
        .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE)
        
        .setDataTable(dataTable)
        .build();
    lineBuilder.setTitle('Engagement Over Time')
        .setYAxisTitle('Published Date');
    statsSheet.insertChart(lineBuilder);
     
  }
```

I've converted the intended structure into JSON for easier reference.

The remove duplicates function works well and it just deduplicates the media category column for unique values, it then cycles through each one, adds that value into the filter section of the JSON and passes it into createDataTable, you can see this here

```
function createDataTable(dataRange,dataTableStructure) {
  var dataSource = dataRange.getValues();

  //created new datatable object
  var data = Charts.newDataTable();

  //cycles through columns and creates the columns
  var columns = dataTableStructure.columns;

  for (var c in columns) {
    data.addColumn(columns[c].type,columns[c].name);
  }

  
  //goes through the data source to get the values and create the row
  var arrSR = 1;
  var filters = dataTableStructure.filters[0];

  for (var arrSR in dataSource) {
    var rows = [];
    if (dataSource[arrSR][filters.filterColumn] == filters.filterValue) {
      for (var r in columns) {
        var colNumber = columns[r].columnNumber;
        rows.push(dataSource[arrSR][colNumber]);
      }
      data.addRow(rows);

    } else {
      continue;
    }
  } 
  data.build();
  return data;
}
```

This creates the datatable that only has the rows with the values corresponding to the media category. If I did this using newChart() and then insert through sheet.insertChart(), I would have to used an **EmbeddedChartBuilder** which is a range, and doesn't have the filter that I need.

As far as I can tell, the datatable is created properly. However, I can't seem to insert it into the table itself at the desired location. I've tried using **newChart()** but see what I wrote above. It doesn't recognise the datatable and when I use **newLineChart()**, which is what I'm supposed to use, and then **insertChart(chart)** I get an error.

I know that this error is caused by the fact that newLineChart uses the Chart API whereas newChart() uses the sheets api and they are separate.

My question is, is there a way to use a custom datatable, like I have, create the line chart using newLineChart() and then insert it into a sheet at the right place?

Comment: If your question is how  to insert a chart created with `Chart` class as a sheets ``EmbeddedChart``, then you can't(but you can probably insert a picture of that chart)

Comment: @TheMaster, I already tried inserting it as a picture, and I didn't like the results. My question is not to create a ```Chart``` as an ```EmbeddedChart``` per se. I just want want to be able to insert the chart as a chart into the document

Comment: Html in Sidebar is another option.

Comment: @TheMaster, not ideal, this is not the only chart I want I want to embed. There is no way to put this on the sheet? Alternatively, is there a way to create a custom range for a normal ```EmbeddedChart``` that only includes the rows that have a particular value in one of the columns?

Comment: I think you can use `=query()` or `filter()` based on dropdowns, on a sheet to filter and use that range for the embedded chart.

Comment: Hmmm...I was hoping to avoid printing out a new range completely, I thought about doing something like that programmatically. I'll give it a try.